# How to setup FlawFinder in vscode [c++]?

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio-code, pip, environment-variables

I installed [C/C++ Advanced Lint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jbenden.c-cpp-flylint) in vscode which comes with support for Static Analyzers. Amongst the list is [FlawFinder](https://dwheeler.com/flawfinder/) which I installed using `pip install FlawFinder`. However I cannot get it to register in vscode, the error I get is **Unable to activate FlawFinder analyzer.**

- I can confirm FlawFinder is installed with `pip list`.
- I have added the Python path which contains the FlawFinder script to my User Environment Variables Path

The path is `c:\'user'\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\Scripts`

Not sure where the issue is.

Comment: Try `python3 -m pip install flawfinder`. I think `pip install flawfinder` installs FlawFinder for python 2.

Comment: Your suggestion installed FlawFinder, however I still get the " **Unable to activate FlawFinder analyzer** " error in vscode. Is there perhaps something I need to add to vscode to read the installation path? Because I get the same error with lizard analyzer, actually all packages that use pip